# How to handle mqtt disconnection on Node-RED?

Tags: exception, mqtt, node-red, disconnect

I'm implementing a draft of a connection between 2 Raspberry and an Arduino, connected via mqtt. I'm working on Node-RED flows and I used mqtt nodes.

As you can see, in mqtt node configuration there is the possibility to send different messages for specific moments (when the subscriber is online, when it goes offline and when it disconnects unexpectedly.
I'd like to catch this last event and handle it. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to handle, the MQTT node will automatically reconnect. The Last Will and Testament message is sent by the broker not the client.

Comment: I want to handle the unexpected disconnection. I don't care if MQTT will automatically reconnect, I just want to start a sequence of nodes with this disconnection as trigger

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the status node, this can be used to monitor other nodes.

[image]

You can point it at the MQTT node and it will report every time the status text (next to the little coloured dot under the node) changes. You can use this to detect the disconnected state.

Beware that it will probably trigger during start up as the node starts disconnected.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this solution soon and eventually accept your answer as solution.